# I can't make a screencast on Ubuntu 17.10 in an Xorg session

Tags: screen, screencast, video-recording

I can't make a screencast.

The options in my login screen didn't work so I edited

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

by deleting the `#` before `WaylandEnable=false` using terminal, and saved the file.

The error remains, even after restarting my laptop.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start recording what is on my screen it just open this link and **NO recording**.

When I use the VLC App to record my screen it gives me this error

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'screen://'. Check the log for details.

Comment: most screen capture programs do not work on wayland (default for 17.10). At the login screen select Ubuntu on Xorg session.

Comment: I can't find At the login screen select Ubuntu on Xorg session

Comment: on my Login Screen i can't open the selection menu only keyboard work  so Is there other way to fix that

Comment: see this post to disable wayland https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367290&p=13670488&viewfull=1#post13670488

Comment: I edit the file as the link say But and restart Ubuntu But the error still

Comment: Looks like it should be repoened... the duplicate says "switch to Xorg" but that doesn't work, making it a pretty different Q

Comment: @Yara Are you sure you're in an Xorg session? What's the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @pomsky i type echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE in terminal and it say x11

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the full VLC complement needs installing as explained by
[Unable to capture screen with VLC on Ubuntu+KDE 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023896/unable-to-capture-screen-with-vlc-on-ubuntukde-17-10)
via the command
`sudo apt install vlc-plugin-access-extra`.