# Unable to capture screen with VLC on Ubuntu+KDE 17.10

Tags: kde, screen, vlc, streaming

I am trying to play screen in a VLC window. (To share-screen on chrome) When I try to capture screen with "Desktop" option it says:

> Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'screen://'.
>   Check the log for details.

In the popup window. I have tried enabling verbose logs, but nothing gets generated in the logs either. I am using KDE. If it helps, the same used to work when I was running mint+cinnamon on this same machine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to get vlc-plugin-access-extra from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/vlc-plugin-access-extra.
Source: https://itsfoss.com/vlc-pro-tricks-linux/.
I'm running Kubuntu 17.10 & Plasma 5.12.4.  I have an Nvidia card, which apparently doesn't play well with Wayland so I'm running X11. First test is not perfect, but it was graphic intensive.  It needs a little tweaking, but at least it didn't fail.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.. you saved me a lot of trouble trying to setup a ffmpeg+vlc alternative..

Comment: Happy to hear that I wasn't too late.  I spent a few hours looking and couldn't find anything useful. I knew I was one of many that was extremely frustrated so I felt obligated to signed up to pass it on.

Answer (score 39):

The already mentioned `vlc-plugin-access` can also be installed using the command line:

```
sudo apt install vlc-plugin-access-extra
```

Comment: this works well also in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Also still works as per Ubuntu 20.04 LTS